# Python support for maven module in intellij

Tags: maven, python-3.x, intellij-idea

I am using intellij IDEA version 11.1.5 on windows and python plugin version is 2.9.2

I am using grinder maven plugin to run the performance tests using grinder. It only supports python(Jython) to run tests. I am not getting any auto suggestions for the python development even though I have installed the python plugin. Python files are also getting displayed as a text files.

Is there any other configuration to enable the auto suggestions for python development?

Answer (score 0):

Your file types are not configured correctly, `.py` is most likely assigned to **Text files** instead of **Python files**, you can fix it in `File` | `Settings` | `File Types`.

There is no support for tests running via Maven, but you can create your own Run/Debug configuration for Python unit tests in IDEA.